# Force display from APU and have discrete GPU for OpenCL?

Tags: gpu, opencl, gpgpu, amd-processor

I need a system for OpenCL programming with the following **restrictions**:

1. The discrete GPU must not run as a display card --> I can do that
   from BIOS
2. The internal GPU of the AMD's APU must be used as display GPU --> I can do that
   from BIOS
3. OpenCL must not recognize the internal APU's GPU and must always
   default to the discrete GPU

**Why do I need this?**

1. It is because I am working on a GPU code that demands the GPU's BIOS
   to be flashed and a custom BIOS to be installed, which makes the GPU
   unusable for display.
2. AMD boards can't boot without VGA card so I am getting an APU that
   has internal GPU.
3. The code base I am working on can't deal with conflicting GPUs so I
   need to disable that (APU's GPU) from OpenCL seeing it.

How can I approach it?

Comment: System configuration questions are off topic here, [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is probably a better location. When you move the question there, you will probably also want to mention your OS.

Comment: What OS and OpenCL driver are you using? Some allow using environment variables to configure behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [AMD OpenCL Programming Guide](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_User_Guide2.pdf), AMD's drivers support the `GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL` environment variable to configure which devices are used (Section 2.3.3):

> In some cases, the user might want to mask the visibility of the GPUs seen by
>   the OpenCL application. One example is to dedicate one GPU for regular graphics operations and the other three (in a four-GPU system) for Compute. To
>   do that, set the GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL environment parameter, which is a comma-separated
>   list variable:
>
> - Under Windows: set GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL=1,2,3
> - Under Linux: export GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL=1,2,3

You'll first need to determine the ordinal for the devices you want to include. For this, I would recommend using [clinfo](https://github.com/Oblomov/clinfo) with the `-l` switch, which will give you a basic tree of the available OpenCL platforms and devices. If the devices are listed with the APU first and then the dedicated GPU, you would want to only enable device 1 (the GPU), and would set the environment variable to `GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL=1`.

Comment: I will try that out. It seems this will make life easier.